# Is a dataframe with row labels either side and header able to be read and interpolated with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

In the table the the left side labels `-60` `-40` `-20` `0` are `direction_1` wind components and is where you would usually enter the table.
The headers are `reference_fuel` and are `3.2` `3.3` `3.4` etc etc.
On the right had side, the numbers listed are `direction_2` wind components.

The wind components on the left are for an aircraft heading in a certain direction `direction_1`. The wind components on the right are for the same aircraft heading in a different direction `direction_2`.

The `reference_fuel` at the top and the two wind components are known prior to coming to this table.

An example:
I have a `reference_fuel` of `4.7`, a `direction_1` wind of `-20` and a `direction_2` wind of `40`. My answer is `542`.

What I am trying to figure out is if it is possible to use this style of table with Pandas. Will I need to break the table into different tables? Is it possible to interpolate if I have `direction_1` wind of `-50` and a `direction_2` wind of `30`?

I would love to be able to just keep the table whole obviously rather than having to split it into different files. I am new to this kind of work so just trying to get my head around it. Thank you.

Here is the copied text of the table if anyone would like:

```
3.2 3.3 3.4 3.5 3.6 3.7 3.8 3.9 4.0 4.1 4.2 4.3 4.4 4.5 4.6 4.7
-60
252 261 271 280 289 297 306 315 323 331 339 348 356 364 372 380 -60
273 283 292 302 311 320 329 338 347 355 364 372 381 389 398 406 -40
292 302 311 321 331 340 349 358 367 376 385 394 403 412 420 429 -20
308 318 328 338 348 358 367 376 386 395 404 413 423 432 441 449 0
322 333 343 353 363 373 383 393 402 412 421 431 440 449 459 468 20
335 346 357 367 377 387 397 407 417 427 436 446 456 465 475 484 40
347 358 369 379 390 400 410 420 430 440 450 460 470 480 489 499 60
-40
268 277 287 296 305 314 323 331 340 349 357 365 374 382 390 399 -60
290 300 310 320 329 338 348 357 366 375 384 393 401 410 419 427 -40
310 321 331 341 350 360 370 379 389 398 407 417 426 435 444 453 -20
328 339 349 359 369 379 389 399 409 419 428 438 447 457 466 476 0
344 355 366 376 386 397 407 417 427 437 447 457 467 477 487 496 20
358 369 380 391 402 412 423 433 444 454 464 474 485 495 505 515 40
371 383 394 405 416 427 437 448 459 469 480 490 501 511 521 532 60
-20
281 291 300 309 319 328 337 346 355 363 372 381 389 398 407 415 -60
305 315 325 335 344 354 364 373 382 392 401 410 419 428 437 446 -40
326 337 347 357 367 377 387 397 407 417 426 436 446 455 465 474 -20
346 356 367 378 388 398 409 419 429 439 449 459 469 479 489 499 0
363 374 385 396 407 417 428 439 449 460 470 481 491 501 512 522 20
378 390 401 412 424 435 446 457 467 478 489 500 510 521 532 542 40
393 404 416 427 439 450 462 473 484 495 506 517 528 539 550 561 60
0
292 302 311 321 330 340 349 358 367 376 385 394 403 412 421 429 -60
318 328 338 348 358 368 377 387 397 406 416 425 435 444 453 463 -40
340 351 362 372 382 393 403 413 423 433 443 453 463 473 483 493 -20
361 372 383 394 405 415 426 437 447 458 468 479 489 499 510 520 0
379 391 402 413 425 436 447 458 469 480 491 502 512 523 534 545 20
396 408 420 431 443 455 466 477 489 500 511 523 534 545 556 567 40
412 424 436 448 460 472 483 495 507 519 530 542 553 565 576 588 60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your data in a pandas dataframe with a [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html) of `dir_1` and `dir_2`.
To interpolate you need to reorganize this 2D structure into a 3D array, then you can use scipy's [`inpterpn`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interpn.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interpn

data = {'dir_1': [-60, -60, -60, -60, -60, -60, -60, -40, -40, -40, -40, -40, -40, -40, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        '3.2': [252, 273, 292, 308, 322, 335, 347, 268, 290, 310, 328, 344, 358, 371, 281, 305, 326, 346, 363, 378, 393, 292, 318, 340, 361, 379, 396, 412], 
        '3.3': [261, 283, 302, 318, 333, 346, 358, 277, 300, 321, 339, 355, 369, 383, 291, 315, 337, 356, 374, 390, 404, 302, 328, 351, 372, 391, 408, 424],
        '3.4': [271, 292, 311, 328, 343, 357, 369, 287, 310, 331, 349, 366, 380, 394, 300, 325, 347, 367, 385, 401, 416, 311, 338, 362, 383, 402, 420, 436],
        '3.5': [280, 302, 321, 338, 353, 367, 379, 296, 320, 341, 359, 376, 391, 405, 309, 335, 357, 378, 396, 412, 427, 321, 348, 372, 394, 413, 431, 448],
        '3.6': [289, 311, 331, 348, 363, 377, 390, 305, 329, 350, 369, 386, 402, 416, 319, 344, 367, 388, 407, 424, 439, 330, 358, 382, 405, 425, 443, 460],
        '3.7': [297, 320, 340, 358, 373, 387, 400, 314, 338, 360, 379, 397, 412, 427, 328, 354, 377, 398, 417, 435, 450, 340, 368, 393, 415, 436, 455, 472],
        '3.8': [306, 329, 349, 367, 383, 397, 410, 323, 348, 370, 389, 407, 423, 437, 337, 364, 387, 409, 428, 446, 462, 349, 377, 403, 426, 447, 466, 483],
        '3.9': [315, 338, 358, 376, 393, 407, 420, 331, 357, 379, 399, 417, 433, 448, 346, 373, 397, 419, 439, 457, 473, 358, 387, 413, 437, 458, 477, 495],
        '4.0': [323, 347, 367, 386, 402, 417, 430, 340, 366, 389, 409, 427, 444, 459, 355, 382, 407, 429, 449, 467, 484, 367, 397, 423, 447, 469, 489, 507],
        '4.1': [331, 355, 376, 395, 412, 427, 440, 349, 375, 398, 419, 437, 454, 469, 363, 392, 417, 439, 460, 478, 495, 376, 406, 433, 458, 480, 500, 519],
        '4.2': [339, 364, 385, 404, 421, 436, 450, 357, 384, 407, 428, 447, 464, 480, 372, 401, 426, 449, 470, 489, 506, 385, 416, 443, 468, 491, 511, 530],
        '4.3': [348, 372, 394, 413, 431, 446, 460, 365, 393, 417, 438, 457, 474, 490, 381, 410, 436, 459, 481, 500, 517, 394, 425, 453, 479, 502, 523, 542],
        '4.4': [356, 381, 403, 423, 440, 456, 470, 374, 401, 426, 447, 467, 485, 501, 389, 419, 446, 469, 491, 510, 528, 403, 435, 463, 489, 512, 534, 553],
        '4.5': [364, 389, 412, 432, 449, 465, 480, 382, 410, 435, 457, 477, 495, 511, 398, 428, 455, 479, 501, 521, 539, 412, 444, 473, 499, 523, 545, 565],
        '4.6': [372, 398, 420, 441, 459, 475, 489, 390, 419, 444, 466, 487, 505, 521, 407, 437, 465, 489, 512, 532, 550, 421, 453, 483, 510, 534, 556, 576],
        '4.7': [380, 406, 429, 449, 468, 484, 499, 399, 427, 453, 476, 496, 515, 532, 415, 446, 474, 499, 522, 542, 561, 429, 463, 493, 520, 545, 567, 588],
        'dir_2': [-60, -40, -20, 0, 20, 40, 60, -60, -40, -20, 0, 20, 40, 60, -60, -40, -20, 0, 20, 40, 60, -60, -40, -20, 0, 20, 40, 60]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(['dir_1', 'dir_2'])
df.columns = df.columns.map(float)
df.columns.name = 'fuel'
```

Your dataframe `df`:

```
fuel         3.2  3.3  3.4  3.5  3.6  3.7  3.8  3.9  4.0  4.1  4.2  4.3  4.4  4.5  4.6  4.7
dir_1 dir_2                                                                                
-60   -60    252  261  271  280  289  297  306  315  323  331  339  348  356  364  372  380
      -40    273  283  292  302  311  320  329  338  347  355  364  372  381  389  398  406
      -20    292  302  311  321  331  340  349  358  367  376  385  394  403  412  420  429
       0     308  318  328  338  348  358  367  376  386  395  404  413  423  432  441  449
       20    322  333  343  353  363  373  383  393  402  412  421  431  440  449  459  468
       40    335  346  357  367  377  387  397  407  417  427  436  446  456  465  475  484
       60    347  358  369  379  390  400  410  420  430  440  450  460  470  480  489  499
-40   -60    268  277  287  296  305  314  323  331  340  349  357  365  374  382  390  399
      -40    290  300  310  320  329  338  348  357  366  375  384  393  401  410  419  427
      -20    310  321  331  341  350  360  370  379  389  398  407  417  426  435  444  453
       0     328  339  349  359  369  379  389  399  409  419  428  438  447  457  466  476
       20    344  355  366  376  386  397  407  417  427  437  447  457  467  477  487  496
       40    358  369  380  391  402  412  423  433  444  454  464  474  485  495  505  515
       60    371  383  394  405  416  427  437  448  459  469  480  490  501  511  521  532
-20   -60    281  291  300  309  319  328  337  346  355  363  372  381  389  398  407  415
      -40    305  315  325  335  344  354  364  373  382  392  401  410  419  428  437  446
      -20    326  337  347  357  367  377  387  397  407  417  426  436  446  455  465  474
       0     346  356  367  378  388  398  409  419  429  439  449  459  469  479  489  499
       20    363  374  385  396  407  417  428  439  449  460  470  481  491  501  512  522
       40    378  390  401  412  424  435  446  457  467  478  489  500  510  521  532  542
       60    393  404  416  427  439  450  462  473  484  495  506  517  528  539  550  561
 0    -60    292  302  311  321  330  340  349  358  367  376  385  394  403  412  421  429
      -40    318  328  338  348  358  368  377  387  397  406  416  425  435  444  453  463
      -20    340  351  362  372  382  393  403  413  423  433  443  453  463  473  483  493
       0     361  372  383  394  405  415  426  437  447  458  468  479  489  499  510  520
       20    379  391  402  413  425  436  447  458  469  480  491  502  512  523  534  545
       40    396  408  420  431  443  455  466  477  489  500  511  523  534  545  556  567
       60    412  424  436  448  460  472  483  495  507  519  530  542  553  565  576  588
```

Reorganize into 3D array of shape `(7, 16, 4)`:

```
arr = np.dstack(np.array_split(df.to_numpy(), 4))         # split into 4 arrays along first axis and stack in depth
dir_2 = df.index.get_level_values(1).unique().to_numpy()  # axis 0
fuel = df.columns.to_numpy()                              # axis 1
dir_1 = df.index.get_level_values(0).unique().to_numpy()  # axis 2
```

Query or interpolate:

```
print(interpn((dir_2, fuel, dir_1), arr, [40, 4.7, -20]))
# array([542.])

print(interpn((dir_2, fuel, dir_1), arr, [30, 4.7, -50]))
# array([490.75])
```

Comment: This is so helpful, thank you so much! It works perfectly! Do you also know if there is there a way I can store the 'data' in a separate file as well (just to reduce my clutter) and then call it in my main.py?

Comment: sure, see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/io.html for different input / output options of the dataframe; if you don't want to store the dataframe but just the data, I'd recomment `csv`.

Comment: Thanks so much @Stef for your help, I really appreciate it. May I ask what method you used to turn the original table that I provided into the 'data' structure that you have there? Somehow you managed to turn the table onto its side.

Comment: I just copied the raw data into a text editor, manually converted the single `dir_1` lines into a column, then copied everything into the clipboard and used [`read_clipboard`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_clipboard.html) to make a dataframe, finally I used `to_dict` to get the `data` dict from the dataframe for the example code.

Comment: Thanks so much for that, you were such a big help and solved everything for me. I am now trying to interpolate again with a different type of dataframe and have asked a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70562007/how-to-use-interpn-to-interpolate-in-a-dataframe?noredirect=1#comment124734502_70562007 may you please have a look at it? I am sure you will know the answer to it. Thank you!